# How to add hot reloading module in react typescript with npm serve

Tags: reactjs, typescript, hot-reload, serve

I'm using the [npm serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) for react localhost with production build.
But when I made a changes, I need to stop the server and build again for `serve -s build`.

So how can I add hot reload with this serve?
I'm using typescript.